# Mongodb not start because of polkitd

Tags: linux, mongodb, fedora-23

I've install mongodb from mongo official repo. When I want to start mongo it fail. When run `journalctl -xe` I got this:

```
Jun 02 11:34:21 mongo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 02 11:34:21 mongo audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mongod comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/syste
Jun 02 11:34:21 mongo systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 02 11:34:21 mongo polkitd[736]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2218:1110034 (system bus name :1.28, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAge
```

I am using fedora 23 server.
How I could fix Unregistered Auth error?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search I find this [link](http://www.opensourcerers.org/howto-workaround-failing-mongodb-on-rhelcentos-7/).
I add this rule to selinux: `semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017` but no success. After I set `SELINUX=permissive` in /etc/selinux/config and reboot, it worked.